# NSNumberFormatter failing with nil value

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I must be missing something very obvious, but I have looked all over and cannot find a solution.

In Interface Builder I have hooked up a NSNumberFormatter to a NSTextField, I have bound the value to a float value. It all works as expected, the number gets validated and updated. Unless I enter an empty string, in which case I get an exception:

```
Exception detected while handling key input.
[<ResolutionSetting 0x11d029430> setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key scale.
```

Is there any way to have the NSTextField return an empty string (@"") instead of nil if the text field is empty? Alternatively, is there a way to have the NSNumberFormatter handle nil values?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of setNilValueForKey: method is to raise an exception. You need to implement this method in your code to override the default behavior. For example to assign a 0.0 value when nothing is entered.
Example:

```
- (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString *)key{
//here you can either assign @"" or 0.0
}
```

You can also specify minimum and maximum values in number formatter attributes inspector.

This topic is covered in "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide" in apple documentation, and also in Chapter 7 of "Cocoa programming for Mac OS X".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this approach, and while it removes the exception it leaves the text field blank. (Instead, it should not allow nil values and pop-up the notification asking the user to enter a valid number.)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `nilSymbol` of your `NSNumberFormatter` to a non-empty string.

The `NSTextField` then no longer throws an exception but complains to the user that `""` is an invalid value. I'm not sure why this works but it's the easiest solution I've found.

```
yourNumberFormatter.nilSymbol = "?"
```